# Deserialize JSON data from JSON array

Tags: c#, json

This question is probably asked a dozen times but i can't find anything useful so...

JSON data looks like this

```
{
"aaData": [
        [
        8120,
        "username",
        "username@hotmail.com",
        "\/",
        "CUSTOMER ( SellerName )",
        "name",
        "<span class=\"label label-danger\">2015-08-05<\/span>",
        "<a class=\"btn btn-xs btn-primary manageDevices\" href=\"#\" id=\"manageDevices\" data-customerid=\"8120\" data-toggle=\"modal\">1<\/a>",
        "<a id=\"8120\" href=\"http:\/\/cms.*********.com:8081\/manageCustomers?customerId=8120\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-primary\">View<\/a>",
        "YES"
         ],
         ....
         ]
     ],
    "sEcho": "NULL",
    "iTotalRecords": 65,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 65
}
```

Obviously, this fails:

```
private class OuterUser
{
    string id { get; set; }
    string username { get; set; }
    string line { get; set; }
    string reseller { get; set; }
    string username2 { get; set; }
    string date1 { get; set; }
    string manage { get; set; }
    string manageUser { get; set; }
    string active { get; set; }
}

dynamic jsonDe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OuterUser>(rpl);
//dynamic j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OuterUser>>(rpl);
```

Anyone has idea how to deserialize this? And explain what i did wrong. I don't need data on bottom (total records) and so on. Actually, only thing that i need is ID on beginning, username and email. Commented code also fails and i think that is part of solution.

Comment: Try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OuterUser[]>(rpl);` as you wrote you need a array. Is there any container object?

Comment: @CSharper - i tried that also but i got this exception:
`An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Also, i think that this "aaData" is some kind of container with rest of those users...
Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'tvTracker.Data.IPTV+OuterUser[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.`

I need a list of those users, or array. Anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you clean up your JSON (remove `....]`) and post it to [Json2Csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/), you'll get:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<List<object>> aaData { get; set; }
    public string sEcho { get; set; }
    public int iTotalRecords { get; set; }
    public int iTotalDisplayRecords { get; set; }
}
```

As the list of values you're interested in seems to be a nested array of various types. That can't be mapped to your `OuterUser` class, as the values aren't in `key: value` notation, they're just array elements.

So you'll have to deserialize to `RootObject`, then step into (or iterate over) the `List<List<object>>`:

```
var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(rpl);
var firstUser = parsed.aaData[0]; 
var firstUserID = firstUser[0]; // 8120
```

Comment: Perfect! Saved link also, seems pretty useful in my wars with JSON. Will accepts answer as soon as site allows it. Thanks!

Comment: It's also built into VS: Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes. This'll give `object[][]` though, but you can iterate or index them just as easily.